# Hard-core bosons and fermions - spinless?

Tags: fermions, bosons, cold-atoms

The introduction to [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.5329.pdf) about bosonic atoms expanding in an optical lattice says the following:

[image]

Are hard-core bosons mapped to *spinless* fermions?

Because [this link](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~sunkai/teaching/Fall_2012/chapter7.pdf) shows the mapping procedure with spin-$1/2$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I found the answer.

The distinction to be made is between a *spin* model and *actuals* spin particles.

1D hard core bosons act as if they were fermions (they cannot have the same quantum numbers and therefore 'repel'), but they do not have spin so they correspond to spinless fermions.

This however corresponds to a *spin $1/2$* model, where there are only 2 states occupied, 'up' or 'down'.